# My 3V relay doesn't work on GPIO but works on 5V pin with resistor

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, electronics

Ok, I have this awkward situation. I have a 3V relay that I need to implement in my project. When I connect it to a 5V pin on RPi, everything's working fine, I can hear the coil opening and current flows from the relay, but when I try to do same thing with GPIO pin (without resistor), it simply doesn't work. I guess, gpio pin doesn't provide enough current to the relay to open the coil, because as far as I know, gpio pin is 3V, just as my relay.

Relay model is [LMR2-3D](http://www.tme.eu/en/details/lmr2-3d/miniature-electromagnetic-relays/rayex-electronic/)

So what's the solution in my situation? I heard that it's possible to increase current for gpio pin, will this solve the issue I have or is there a better solution?

P.S. As you may have guessed, I'm quite new to electronics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coil need 180mA at 3V to operate.  The most you can safely take from a gpio is circa 16mA (and circa 50mA from the 3V3 rail as a whole).

Even if you could supply the needed current from the gpio you shouldn't.  When the coil is de-energised the back EMF could destroy the gpio and/or the Pi.

You'll need at least a transistor to act as a switch and a flyback diode to protect against back EMF.  Google the terms.

I'd use a ULN2003A or similar in preference to transistors/resistors/diodes as I find it easier to understand digital devices.  The ULN2003A could safely switch the relay in response to a gpio signal.

Answer (score 1):

The issue - as you already figured by yourself - is the limited current that can (or better to say: should) be drawn from a GPIO pin. A buffer/amplifier is mandatory to provide this large a current. Chances are that those IO pins are already blown by this experiment...

A simple single-transistor buffer (w/o optocoupler) is also shown in [Can I Use this Relay Board with pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23115/can-i-use-this-relay-board-with-pi/23119)